# Jenkins EnvInject plugin + Scripted Pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using EnvInject plugin to inject the version into my xml files before the build. This EnvInject plugin works fine in freestyle job. However, I am not sure how we can use this scripted Jenkins Pipeline.

Please find the image below. The file **variables.properties** contain this value ***FinalVer=1.7.9***

Any suggestion on this would be helpful.

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, envInject plugin is not supported for pipeline jobs